# complete workspace duplicate files open in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, workspace

within my solution in Visual Studio I have the problem that somehow sometimes all open files in my workspace are duplicated, followed by :1, :2, :...

[image]

I can't find a reason why this is happening, and can't find any information on the web about this "issue" too.
I found a way to duplicate one file, using the Windows > New Window option in Visual Studio, but can't find the reason why all files are duplicated.

[image]

The main problem is that I don't know when it happens, I suddenly notice the numbers behind the files. I then close all documents, and after a while (sometimes a day later) it happens again.

Does someone knows when this occurs, How I can prevent this from happening?